# I'm looking for something as strong as Acetone

Tags: everyday-chemistry

We use Acetone to remove nail polish and gel polish at our salon.  Is there another  alternative substance out there with less irritated smell like Acetone?

Comment: Most nail polish remover now days is actually made from ethyl acetate. It does the same job but with lower toxicity

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Feel free to take the short [tour] or visit the [help] if you have any questions or to learn more about how this site works. Best of luck with your question!

Comment: Reviewers please note, this question isn't asking for the *best* or anything. He/She simply wants an alternative to acetone, with a clear definition that it should be less volatile (and less irritating to the nose) than acetone.

Comment: Hmm...I like the smell of acetone better than that of EtOAc, but well, that's a personal opinion...

Answer (score 1):

Mineral oil is often used to remove nail polish. Give it a try (J&J has a great one for babies with a soft smell).